# I am not taking my accent in the ModelAndView

Tags: java, html, jsp

I'm not getting it to take the accent on the a in the return of the model

```js
@RequestMapping(value="/resetPassword", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView passwordReset(@RequestParam String username, @RequestParam String mail){
        
        Map<String, Object> filter = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        filter.put("usuario", username);
        filter.put("mail", mail);
        
        Usuario usuario = usuarioManager.findUnique(filter);
        
        if(usuario != null)
            mailServiceManager.solicitudResetClave(usuario.getMail(), usuario.getEntidadMm().getNombre(), usuario.getId());
        return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("/login?mensaje=Si los datos son validos, te llegara un email con los pasos para recuperar tu clave. Verific\u00e1 tu casilla para continuar."));
    }
```

[error!!accent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6He78.png)

Comment: Which character are you getting, instead of **á** ?

Comment: There is what I show in the photo, I pull out a question mark

Answer (score 0):

That character means that your page declared its content is encoded with UTF-8, but it is actually encoded with ISO-8859-1.

If you prefer to stick to UTF-8, then you have to find into your code where the ISO-8859-1 encoding is being slipped. I suggest to set UTF-8 with `setEncodingScheme` in your RedirectView object.